# Bootstrap 4 making fontawesome or lineawesome icons responsive

Tags: bootstrap-4

Is there a way to make icons responsive in bootstrap 4?

I am using line awesome by icons8. These icons are derived from the font awesome icons.

```
<div class="col-md-2">
    <center>
        <a href="my url">
            <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h1 class="display-4">
                        <i class="la la-credit-card"></i>
                    </h1>
                    <p class="card-text">My Text</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </center>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can change the size of the icon in fontawesome by using a class like    `fa-2x` or    `fa-3x`.
Example :    `<i class="fa fa-credit-card fa-2x">` where    `1x` is the original size and you can use classes like    `2x` or    `3x` to increase the size. Similarly you can do so in lineawesome.

Comment: I know how to resize icons with 2x or 3x.  But this doesn't solve the problem of icons overflowing a card if the screen is minimized.

Answer (score 0):

Using a combination of the Bootstrap breakpoints and the sizes of the FA icon, which goes from `fa-1x`, as mentioned above, up to `fa-10x`. Better I share my codepen. Honesty, I don‘t find anything easier than this. [Something that simulates the responsivness.](https://codepen.io/limakid/pen/LYQwyQq?editors=1000)